# Problemas conectar java con mysql red local

Tags: java, mysql

Tengo un servidor `Mysql` instalado y iniciado en una `Raspberry pi` con dirección local 192.xxx.0.1xx conectada a la red y desde otro ordenador intento establecer una conexión con un programa de `Java` con este código:

```
public class BaseDatosMySQL {

private Connection conexion;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    BaseDatosMySQL baseDatos = new BaseDatosMySQL();
    baseDatos.conectar();
    Tabla tabla = new Tabla(baseDatos.getConexion());
    String[] nombreColumnas = { "id", "nick" };
    String[] tipoColumnas = { "INT AUTO_INCREMENT, PRIMARY KEY(id)", "TEXT" };
    tabla.crearTabla("usuarios", nombreColumnas, tipoColumnas);
    baseDatos.desconectar();
}

public void conectar() {
    try {

        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        conexion = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://1XX.168.0.1XX/localhost:3306/ChatEscrito",
                "root", "lapasscorrecta");
        System.out.println("Conexion a la base de datos realizada");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void desconectar() {
    try {
        conexion.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public Connection getConexion() {
    return conexion;
}

public void setConexion(Connection conexion) {
    this.conexion = conexion;
}
```

}

Lo que me produce estos errores:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications     link failure
The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:989)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:341)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2192)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2225)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2024)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:779)
at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:389)
at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:330)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
at cuerpo.BaseDatosMySQL.conectar(BaseDatosMySQL.java:30)
at cuerpo.BaseDatosMySQL.main(BaseDatosMySQL.java:16)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Conexión rehusada (Connection refused)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:211)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:300)
... 16 more
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at utilidades.Tabla.crearTabla(Tabla.java:22)
at cuerpo.BaseDatosMySQL.main(BaseDatosMySQL.java:20)
```

A ver si pueden ayudarme.

> Nota: Se oculta dirección IP publica  por  `xx`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que se encuentra mal en tu código es la linea donde formas la URL de la conexión a MySQL. Quedando de la siguiente manera:

```
conexion = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://1XX.168.0.1XX:3306/ChatEscrito","root", "lapasscorrecta");
```

Ya que se apunta hacia la IP de tu maquina server.

Comment: Lo acabo de probar y me saca el mismo error

Comment: Tienes configurado el acceso del firewall? Checa este link http://www.javamexico.org/foros/java_standard_edition/como_conectar_dos_maquinas_una_base_de_datos

Comment: Gracias encontre la solucion en el post, simplemente tenia que permitir el acceso remoto desde el servidor al parecer por defecto solo tiene permitido el acceso local

Answer (score 0):

Es porque el servidor en tu raspberry no tiene activo el acceso remoto.

Debes modificar el archivo en /etc/mysql/my.cnf

Busca la siguiente línea:

```
bind-address           = 127.0.0.1
```

Y coméntala añadiendo # delante:

```
#bind-address           = 127.0.0.1
```

Después reinicia el servicio.

¡Cuidado! Con esto haces que cualquier ip se pueda conectar al servidor, si sólo quieres que se conecte una ip, en lugar de comentar la línea puedes poner la ip del equipo que va a acceder.